# React-native use react-native-vector-icons in android module

Tags: java, android, font-awesome, react-native

I'm writing a module for react-native that should run on android, I have to do so to take a react-native-vector-icons and switch it to the module to be able to use them as a Drawable image.

To use the type of icons: FontAwesome, Entypo, Ionicons, MaterialIcons and etc.

I found something like that, but I did not understand how it works or how to make it work in my case.

Link: [here](https://github.com/prscX/react-native-bottom-action-sheet/blob/master/android/src/main/java/ui/bottomactionsheet/RNBottomActionSheetModule.java#L212-L249)

```
@TargetApi(21)
  private Drawable generateVectorIcon(ReadableMap icon) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    String family = icon.getString("family");
    String name = icon.getString("name");
    String glyph = icon.getString("glyph");
    String color = icon.getString("color");
    int size = icon.getInt("size");

    if (name != null && name.length() > 0 && name.contains(".")) {
      Resources resources = getReactApplicationContext().getResources();
      name = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf("."));

      final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getReactApplicationContext().getPackageName());
      return getReactApplicationContext().getDrawable(resourceId);
    }

    float scale = getReactApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    String scaleSuffix = "@" + (scale == (int) scale ? Integer.toString((int) scale) : Float.toString(scale)) + "x";
    int fontSize = Math.round(size * scale);

    Typeface typeface = ReactFontManager.getInstance().getTypeface(family, 0, getReactApplicationContext().getAssets());
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTypeface(typeface);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    paint.setTextSize(fontSize);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    Rect textBounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(glyph, 0, glyph.length(), textBounds);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(textBounds.width(), textBounds.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawText(glyph, -textBounds.left, -textBounds.top, paint);

    return new BitmapDrawable(getReactApplicationContext().getResources(), bitmap);
  }
```

Some advice?